# If $f \in L^{1}(\mathbb{T})$ and $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} |{\hat{f}(n)}| < \infty $ then $f \in C^{0}(\mathbb{T})$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Where $ \mathbb{T} = \mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}.$

My initial thoughts are that if I can show that $ \frac{1}{2\pi}(f*F_{N}) \rightarrow f$ uniformly then I can use a previous result to show that $f \in C^{0}(\mathbb{T})$.

However showing this seems quite difficult. Is this the correct way to proceed or is there a simpler method?

Comment: You have absolute uniform convergence of polynomials to $f$

Comment: can you clarify?

Answer (score 2):

As $\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}|\hat f(n)|<\infty$, we know that the Fourier series $\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\hat f(n)e^{int}, t\in\mathbb T$ converges absolutely and uniformly on $\mathbb T$. However, the partial sum $\sum_{|n|\le N}\hat f(n)e^{int}$ of the Fourier series is continouus on $\mathbb T$ for all $N\in\mathbb Z_{\ge 0}$. By the [Uniform limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_limit_theorem), we conclude that the limit function $f\in C^0(\mathbb T)$.